# DropDownList htmlOptions

Tags: php, yii

Добрый вечер.
Вывожу

$form->dropDownList($model, 'status_color', CHtml::listData(Color::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'color_name'));

Хотел сделать вместо названий цветов розкрашивать фон чтобы пользователь понимал что выбирает. Но не знаю как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

CHtml::listData не используйте. Делайте все руками. Цвета делайте через css.

Comment: Спасиба.))